# Unable to unpack the data if data is greater than 64bytes in Protocol buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Im unable to unpack the data if PeriodAndControlByte is greater than 15.please look at my code snippet.
proto file is written in the below format

```
message LockingPlanAutoChanges
{   
     uint32 RecordPointer = 1;      
     repeated uint32 PeriodAndControlByte = 2; /* Repeat 64 times to send 8 auto changes data */
}




 uint32_t auto_days[] = {
  0x8010,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000};
  LockingPlanAutoChanges autoMsg;
  LockingPlanAutoChanges *msg;
  uint8_t len =0;
  uint8_t buf[250] ;
  locking_plan_auto_changes__init(&autoMsg);
  autoMsg.recordpointer = 1;
  autoMsg.n_periodandcontrolbyte = 60; 
  autoMsg.periodandcontrolbyte = auto_days;
  
  len = locking_plan_auto_changes__get_packed_size(&autoMsg);
  len = locking_plan_auto_changes__pack(&autoMsg, buf);

   asm("nop");
   asm("nop");
   
  msg = locking_plan_auto_changes__unpack(NULL, len, buf);  
  locking_plan_auto_changes__free_unpacked(msg, NULL);
```

if my n_periodandcontrolbyte is greater than 15, im unable to unpack the message, giving a null pointer

Comment: What is `len` here? Is it possible you've exceeded the buffer? In particular, what is `len` after **both** assignments (just in case the second one returns something like -1 to indicate failure)

Comment: `len` is 0x51,Im not exceeding the buffer, len is within range after packing the message